# Twig: attribute from html element filter/function

Tags: twig, grav

I am using the grav flatfile cms, and i have a twig variable that outputs something like:

```
<img src="example.com/path/to/image.jpg">
```

Is there a twig filter that can give me just the URL for the image (the contents of the `src` attribute)? or is there some regex filter that could help me?

Comment: Replace filter, but it replace string constants, not regs.